# jQuery, If file input extension is .pdf then run function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to run a function if a file input type is pdf.

Does anybody know of a way i can validate the file extension with jQuery before hand? thanks

```
$('.uploadCV').click(function () {

    if ($('.html-btn').val() === '.pdf') {

        $('.join-us').flip({
            direction: 'rl',
            color: '#38404b',
            speed: 200,
            onAnimation: function () {
                $('.icon').fadeOut();
                $(this).css('margin-top', '20px');
            },
            content: '<span class="title">Uploading...</span><span class="summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>'
        })
    } else {
        console.log('dont upload');
    }
});
```

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606842/how-can-i-get-a-files-upload-size-using-simple-javascript/1606861#1606861

Answer (score 3):

[**fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VvbQW/3/)

You can check file extension `.pdf`

```
var val = $('.html-btn').val();
var file_type = val.substr(val.lastIndexOf('.')).toLowerCase();
if (file_type  === '.pdf') {
```

References

[.substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

[.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

[.lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if string ends with `.pdf`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VvbQW/2/)**

```
fileName = $('.html-btn').val().toLowerCase();
if(fileName.indexOf('.pdf') == fileName.length - 4) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In this plugin you can determine what extension can to upload
[**Jquery Multiple File Upload Demo**](http://hayageek.com/examples/jquery/jquery-multiple-file-upload/index.php)