# How can I find size of the file before POST-ing the data?

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload

I just realized that one can only POST about 8 MB of data. I have a form to upload multiple files. This files are sent to a php page through POST method where it gets uploaded. Now, I want to check the size of data which will be posted and give an alert message. How can I do that?  I googled a bit and found that $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] can be used to find this. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to use it? 
Here's my form:

```
<form name="offer" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="fileupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <tr>
        <td>I9:</td>
        <td> Doc: <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile[]"><p id="list"></p></td>
     </tr>
     <tr >
       <td>Client document: </td>
       <td> Doc: <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile[]"></td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>FCRA :</td>
         <td> Doc: <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile[]"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Insurance Certificate :</td>
        <td> Doc: <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile[]"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Work Order :</td>
         <td> Doc: <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile[]"></td>
      </tr>
```

Also, is it possible to display the size of each uploaded file? I know this can be done by javascript. But how?

Comment: Why not modify the php.ini to allow larger uploads?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606842/how-can-i-get-a-files-upload-size-using-simple-javascript  -- top voted answer here is good/simple

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497404/get-file-size-before-uploading   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation

Comment: since they are all the same id it will be somewhat more difficult, but input.files[0].size contains the size of a file in a populated input.

Answer (score -2):

use this for client side

```
function findSize() {
    var fileInput =  document.getElementById("_ufile_1");
    try{
        alert(fileInput.files[0].size); // Size returned in bytes.
    }catch(e){
        var objFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var e = objFSO.getFile( fileInput.value);
        var fileSize = e.size;
        alert(fileSize);    
    }
}
```