# How to validate file size and type in <p:fileUpload mode="simple">?

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

In PrimeFaces 3.4, the `<p:fileUpload>` attributes `sizeLimit` and `allowTypes` doesn't work in case of `mode="simple"`. How can I validate the file size and allowable types?

Comment: Any reason for restricting yourself to use simple mode. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697605/limit-the-size-of-an-file-upload-html-input) might help you understand if you are looking for a client side solution as simple mode uses native browser upload with no restrictions.

Comment: I am using simple mode because of two reasons: (a) I just to restrict the number of files to be uploaded to ONE and (b) I want the file to be uploaded in click of form submit button.

Answer (score 6):

The `mode="simple"` generates a plain HTML5 `<input type="file">` instead of using jQuery/Ajax file upload, so the client side facilities are limited.

If the webbrowser supports the new [HTML5 `File` API](http://caniuse.com/fileapi), then you could just make use of it. It adds support for the new `accept` attribute on `<input type="file">` and enables JavaScript to have access to specific file properties such as `File#size`.

E.g.

```html
<p:fileUpload mode="simple" styleClass="imagesOnlyMax10MB" />
```

with this JS (using jQuery from PrimeFaces):

```js
$("input[type=file].imagesOnlyMax10MB").attr("accept", "image/*").on("change", function() {
    var max = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10MB

    if (this.files && this.files[0].size > max) {
        alert("File too large."); // Do your thing to handle the error.
        this.value = null; // Clears the field.
    }
});
```

Otherwise, your best bet is really validating it in the server side. You could use [`ExternalContext#getMimeType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getMimeType%28java.lang.String%29) to get a mime type based on file extension (you can manage all mime types as `<mime-mapping>` in `web.xml`; the container's own one has a bunch of default ones).

```
if (!externalContext.getMimeType(filename).startsWith("image/")) {
    // Not an image.
}
```