# Upload file size restriction in html

Tags: javascript, html, file

I know there is a way to restrict the size using jQuery. But is there a way to restrict the size in the HTML element itself? Kind of like accept in `<input type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png"/>`?

Or does it have to be done in JavaScript. Also what if someone has JavaScript disabled? Then the only line of defense is the server right?

So how can I restrict the size of the file uploaded without using jQuery?

Comment: It's possible (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697605/limit-the-size-of-an-file-upload-html-input). However... you absolutely should enforce this on the server side too.

Comment: @JordanS Both of these answers show a JavaScript way of doing it

Comment: So there is your answer. Not in HTML but in JavaScript

Comment: So there is no way to restrict the size just in HTML?

Comment: No there is not