# I want to limit file size on paste

Tags: javascript, summernote

I'm working with summernote, the problem we currently are facing is, how to limit the size of a file when a user pastes it. We already disabled the tool, so no upload through that.

The only way that images can be added is through paste (<kbd>ctrl+v</kbd>). We want to allow only images under 2 MB to be added.

```
$('textarea.summernote').summernote({
      toolbar:[],
      height: h,
      maximumImageFileSize: 2097152,
      callbacks: {
        onPaste: function(e) {
          //Do Something
        }
      }

});
```

Even though we specified `maximumImageFileSize`, it's still possible to paste images above the 2 MB limit, or to resize it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a bit more effort into this. Actually, client side upload size restrictions used to be completely impossible. Today, you can do it with a bit of JavaScript. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697605/limit-the-size-of-an-file-upload-html-input/17173301#17173301) on SO.

Comment: So, it's not a upload, and it's a paste on summernote, I tried that, and others JS methods, but to no avail.