# Cannot get size of image, but length is OK?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Here is my code:**

```
    var image = $('#image_gms');
    console.log(image[0].files.length);
    console.log(image[0].files.size);
```

**And result:**

```
1
undefiend
```

So `files.length` returns me 1 (there is an image) but cannot get the size, i'm following second answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697605/limit-the-size-of-an-file-upload-html-input/17173301#17173301) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `image[0].files` is something that has length === 1, I'm assuming an array *or an array-like object*. Therefore, to get the file's size, do

```
image[0].files[0].size
```

Comment: When you say, "I'm assuming an array". That's wrong.  `image[0].files` return a `FileList` object. You can get the size of an `File` object with the property `size`.

Answer (score 1):

`image[0].files` return a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList).  The property `length` return the number of `File` into the list.
If you want the size of a file, you can use the property `size` directly on a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object.

Like :

```
image[0].files[0].size

// or

const sizes = []
for (let l = image[0].files.length; l--;) {
  var file = files.item(l);
  sizes.push(file.size)
}
console.log(sizes)
```