# Is there a maximum size for a file upload through HTML form?

Tags: html, upload

I want users on my site to be able to upload large files (say up to 1GB), through html form. What I have so far, which works:

```
  <h1>Upload new File:</h1>
  <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type=file name=file>
    <input type=submit value=Upload>
  </form>
```

Will this work for large files ? Or should I use another way (considering that I'm a beginner in webdev) ?
I can't find references of a limitation on file size in html5 documentation, and only found ways to *limit* file size on SO (e.g. [Limit the size of an file upload (html input)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697605/limit-the-size-of-an-file-upload-html-input)).

Comment: There isn't one. You should ideally create one yourself or users can upload massive files and fill your server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no size upload limit in Html input type "file"...

Following are the way if you want to check file uploaded size.

```
if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {
var Filesize = document.getElementById('fileId').files[0].size;}
```

There are several configuration parameters that can affect the file upload. These configuration parameters have to be setup right for the file uploads to work fine.

=> The folder in which the files are saved should be writable by the script. This is obvious but might be overlooked. The folder must be writable by the script means the web server user (usually www-data ) should have write access to the folder. So setup the folder permissions right. If you have shell access, the folder permissions can be updated using the 'chmod' command easily. If you don't have shell access, or if you have a shared hosting account, updating the folder permissions can be a little tricky. See if your hosting control panel has this feature.

=> The websever configuration The web server would have a configuration setting that (1) allows/disallows file uploads (2) sets a limit on the size of the file upload. Here are the typical settings you have to check (for PHP)

1. memory_limit
2. upload_max_filesize
3. post_max_size

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that, here in 2024, there is no size limit for files uploaded from an HTML web page. I do recall in the early 2010s that browsers had a 2 GB limit (and you could use a Flash app which had a 3 GB limit) but that's gone now.

I tested this on my Windows 10 machine in Firefox 121.0.1 browser, uploading a 19 GB file and it works just as well as uploading a 10 KB file. (I assume other modern browsers work too.)

For testing, I ran the following Flask app on my local machine (you must have Python installed and run `pip install flask` for the Flask web app framework):

In an app.py file, I have the following Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

HTML = '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload File</title>
    <h1>Upload File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file:
            file.save('this_is_the_uploaded_filename')
            return 'File saved as this_is_the_uploaded_filename'
    return render_template_string(HTML)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Then I run `python app.py` from the terminal and open my browser to http://localhost:5000 to get the web page with a simple file upload form. I tested it with a giant 19 GB file and it worked fine (as long as you have free disk space for the uploaded copy on your machine.)