# HTML file input window limit size?

Tags: html

I am using input file and I am able to limit the file type in the file dialog window like so:

```
<input type="file" name="logoIMG" id="logoIMG" class="" accept=".png">
```

I am just wondering if I could limit the file size so the user can only pick files 2 MB or less?

Comment: With `JS` or `jQuery`  = Big yes **VS** Just HTML = no

Comment: for limit size u need to go with jquery or javascript

Comment: Any suggestions on jquery library?

Comment: You do not need a library. There are so many answers here on `stackoverflow` to limit file size via JS or jQuery. [Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697605/limit-the-size-of-a-file-upload-html-input-element/17173301#17173301) OR [Here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307679/using-jquery-restricting-file-size-before-uploading)

Answer (score 1):

You can't handle with HTML code u need to write some code for validation on file size limit

For Example :

```
var uploadField = document.getElementById("file");

uploadField.onchange = function() {
    if(this.files[0].size > 2097152){
       alert("File is too big!");
       this.value = "";
    };
};
```

This example should work fine. I set it up for roughly **2MB**, **1MB** in **Bytes** is **1,048,576** so you can multiply it by the limit you need.

Check or preview [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7bjfr/808/)

---

You Can also go with JQuery like this

```js
$("input[type='file']").on("change", function() {
  if (this.files[0].size > 2000000) {
    var size = this.files[0].size;
    size = ( size >>> 20 ) + '.' + ( size & (2*0x3FF ) ) + '  ' ;
    alert("Please upload file less than  and your file size is " + size + " Thanks!! ");
    $(this).val('');
    return size;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<input type="file">
```

Comment: You `COPIED` this `code` from here: https://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/7bjfr/ and *made it your own fiddle*. **Its not good.** If you want to help out someone just add a comment in the question to direct them to the right place.

Comment: yes @AlwaysHelping u correct but i just posted same answer and i want to add jquery code also that why i have posted both code javascript and jquery for better understanding and BTW i know how to answer 

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the size by using javascript but I don't think you can do it only using html.

There is a similar question on stack that you might find usefull : [Limit the size of a file upload (html input element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697605/limit-the-size-of-a-file-upload-html-input-element/17173301#17173301)

Answer (score 0):

file upload size limit using javascript.
const maxAllowedSize = 3 * 1024 * 1024; //this means max file size 3 mb

```js
const doc_input = document.getElementById('file_upload')

doc_input.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
const target = event.target
    if (target.files && target.files[0]) {

    const maxAllowedSize = 3 * 1024 * 1024;
    if (target.files[0].size > maxAllowedSize) {
        alert('Choose max 3mb files');
        target.value = ''
    }
}
})
```

```html
<input id="file_upload" type="file" />
```

Answer (score -1):

The min and max properties have the smallest and largest properties allowed for an  element. min and max properties; Used with number, range, date, datetime, datetime-local, month, hour and week type.