# restrict image file size in alloy UI

Tags: jsp-tags, liferay-6, alloy-ui

I am making a simple form using Alloy UI. It has an image upload field. I want to restrict image file size say, to less than 10MB.

I have tried `<aui:validator name="min">` and `<aui:validator name="max">` in my `view.jsp`.

But, this is not working.

What should be used here to restrict image file size?

Comment: If you want good response for your question, you should paste your code and exceptions(if any)...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want a validation of file size on the client side i.e. using Alloy UI javascript, so I am sorry to bring to your notice that this is not possible in pre-HTML5 browsers due to some security reasons but this is possible with browsers which support the [File-API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) in HTML5. Here is a [good-demo site](http://html5demos.com/file-api) for the file-API.

So for now I would suggest that you do this server-side as a fallback mechanism & there are different plugins available to help you do this using Ajax or just go with plain server-side validation.

You can also try using flash with alloy-ui to check file-size as liferay does in its Documents & Media portlet. The drawback with this approach is that it requires flash to be installed in your browser.

Here is a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3717847/468763) which may help you give more information about client-side validation alongwith a demo.

Hope this would give you some lead.