# Javascript returns wrong file size, when using ASP.NET (aspx pages) for uploading

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file-upload

I am uploading a file in an ASP.NET application, I need to get the file size for some client side validation. Following the advice I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation/3717829#3717829). I have something like this:

in aspx:

```
<td class="form_input_bold">
            <asp:FileUpload Width="80%" ID="fuUploadFile" CssClass="button" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" />                
        </td>
```

And in Javascript:

```
var inputFile = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fuUploadFile');
alert("File size: " + inputFile.size);
```

Now for some reason, when I try to upload a 50 MB file, `inputFile.size` returns 20. Can anyone tell why this is? ASP.NET is getting the correct size server side..

Comment: You are using a modern browser, right?

Comment: @JoeEnos Yes, I tried the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Not sure if this is your real code, but if so, you should modify it so that you're not hard-coding the client control ID - instead do `document.getElementById("<%= fuUploadFile.ClientID %>")`, which will render the way you have it.

Comment: @JoeEnos Its not hard coded, but it does use my company's internal Javascript API and I don't want to give anyone a migraine by posting that here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file's size is found in the element of the `files` array of the input control.

```
var numBytes = document.getElementById("fu1").files[0].size;
```