# Security issues of let users save files from URL

Tags: php

I'm developing a script to grab **small sized files (less than 1 MB)** from user given a URLs and save them on my server.

My main concern is what if someone tried to upload large files like **1 GB** files or even bigger? How do I control the  file grabbing if it is a large file?

I tried some of the answers on the web but all of them process the whole file. For a `700 MB` video file, it took couple of minutes, does that mean the process taking my server resources?

What if a hacker keep posting URLs to large files so those process will eat up my server resources and I will loose visitors.

Can someone advice me on this?

Comment: PHP has [`upload_max_filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) and [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) settings which will solve your problem - the biggest issue is making sure the user isn't posting anything malicious - executable code that could be run on your server.

Comment: That's a great point! All I have to do is change max upload size, then take care of file types in PHP. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. No file bigger than 1 megabyte can be uploaded

```
if($_FILES['file']['size'] < 1048576) { // This is one megabyte (in bytes)
    // the file is within size restriction, continue
} else {
    // File is too large, return an error
}
```

Then you could use some javascript to test the file size before upload, but just remember you can't rely on it for security.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your upload file size here. Like this

```
<?php
ini_set('post_max_size', '20K'); // If you need it like 10 MB , Set is as 10M
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20K');
```

Answer (score -1):

**Ninja edit: Not a good answer for security purposes**

you can check the file size in javascript so you don't need to send it to the server. You can find the full explanation here: [JavaScript file upload size validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation)

Comment: When the question concerns security, client-side validation isn't a good answer :/

Comment: True, you could just evade the filecheck and send any file with an easy script