# how to check file size before upload in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I use this code for check file type

```
// - coursesweb.net
  // get the file name and split it to separe the extension
  var name = el.value;
  var ar_name = name.split('.');
```

but now i want to apply this code to get file size , how can i do ?

[code from this site](http://coursesweb.net/javascript/check-file-type-before-upload_t)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation

Answer (score 12):

> ```
> You can check the filesize by files[0].size
> ```
>
> > 
>
> try the following:
>
> ```
> $('#myFile').bind('change', function() {
>
>   //this.files[0].size gets the size of your file.
>   alert(this.files[0].size);
>
> });
> ```

Comment: +1 upvoted as this is a legitimate answer and the downvote without a comment is unacceptable

Answer (score 5):

try this to get file size

```
document.getElementById('fileid').addEventListener('change', checkFile, false);

function checkFile(e) {
    var file_list = e.target.files;
    for (var i = 0, file; file = file_list[i]; i++) {
        var fileExtension = file.name.split('.')[file.name.split('.').length - 1].toLowerCase();
        var iConvert = (file.size / 1024).toFixed(2);

        txt = "File type : " +fileExtension + "\n";
        if(file.size > (1024 * 1024)){
            txt += "Size: " + (file.size / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2) + " MB \n";
        } else {
        txt += "Size: " + (file.size / 1024).toFixed(2) + " KB \n";
        }
        alert(txt);
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/har1236/aHebc/)

Comment: is this compatible with older browsers?

Comment: i did not try with older browsers, but I think it will work fine with older browsers..

Answer (score 2):

If browser supports [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/).

```
if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {
    var size = document.getElementById('file_input_field_id').files[0].size;
} else {
    console.log("File API is not supported");
    var size = -1;
}
```

If you want to get file size on client side w/o File API, needs to use flash. You can use lib like  [FileAPI.js](http://mailru.github.io/FileAPI/#en/FileAPI.getFiles) for this

Comment: browser not supports File API.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the file size like this.

Lets say your HTML is:

```
<input type="file" id="file" />

 var size = document.getElementById('file').files[0].size;
```

Comment: can you show me for example , thank ^_^

Comment: @user2979339 It is an example!! your input field has an id file and var size gets the size !!