# Where does spring stores large files for upload?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

When using CommonsMultipartResolver for file uploads where does spring stores larger files while processing them ?

We have a js check for the size and we put a maxUploadSize. If a user bypasses the js control and sends a huge file, what does spring do to process it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It will be interesting to know how we can get file size using js.

Comment: There are answers on stackoverflow [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CommonsMultipartResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartResolver.html) will save to the Servlet container's temporary directory.

You can limit the size of uploads by setting `maxUploadSize` property (default is 10240 bytes).

for example:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="o.s.w.m.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
  ...
  <property name="maxUploadSize" value="###"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I assume its 'java.io.tmpdir'. The documentation of CommonsFileUploadSupport, implies that there is a property 'uploadTempDir' that can be set to change this default behavior. But what about the cleanup of these files ? Does spring handles this on his own ?

Comment: No, you need to manage the removal of files (e.g. daily/weekly cron job to remove old/processed files).