# CakePHP, Amazon Elasticbeanstalk and S3

Tags: cakephp, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm planning to move 3 CakePHP 1.3.x applications from an ol' VM to [AWS elasticBeanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/fr/elasticbeanstalk/).

As AWS EB is stateless, customers pictures/pdf have to be moved to S3 (files not versionned, and not meant to).

Working with CakePHP & S3 is ok, now I have to manage how files will be uploaded. I want to avoid transferring file from browser to EB, and next to S3 **BUT** each file should be uploaded to S3 only when the model is validated, and the model can't validate until he "knows" about the file (size, extension, etc).

As a mingy developer, I'm willing to know if there's a solution to that problem!

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation

Comment: It means I would validate the picture only before uploading it, I also need to validate model before uploading picture to S3!

Comment: The only way to validate a picture without sending it to an instance, before sending it to s3 is to use javascript or AWS Lambda.