# How to show only .pdf file when browse file to upload using Laravel 5.0?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, file-upload, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.0. I have a file upload function. It's going well. But I want to make the user only uploaded pdf files. I want when browse a file, the storage only show files with only .pdf files. And I want to have a size limit to file which want to upload.

> Here is the view

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="upload_file" class="control-label col-sm-2">Upload File</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input class="form-control" type="file" name="upload_file" id="upload_file" required>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

> Here is the controller

```
$destination = 'files';

    if($request->hasFile('upload_file')) {
        $file = $request->file('upload_file');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file_name =  str_replace('/','_',$request['nomor_surat']) . '-' . $kode_divisi[0]->kode_divisi . '.' . $extension;

        $file->move($destination, $file_name );
    }
    $upload_file = $file_name;

    $surat = new Surat();
    $surat->upload_file = $upload_file;
    $surat->save();
```

and what should I do next? what should I add in my controller and route and view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can limit the user to browse PDF files only with the HTML file input `accept` attribute:

```
<input type="file" accept="application/pdf" />
```

To limit the size, you can do it on the server side:

```
$file = $request->file('upload_file');

//no files larger than 700kb
if ($file->getSize() > 700000)
{
    //respond not validated, file too big.
}
```

You can also validate the file type on the server as well:

```
if ($file->getClientMimeType() !== 'application/pdf')
{
    //respond not validated, invalid file type.
}
```

Comment: anyway do you know how to make respond file too big like an alert when we push the submit button?
I am using `if ($file->getSize() > 700000)
{
   echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
}`

Comment: When doing this check on the server side, the file will be uploaded first. This sometimes can be a waste of bandwidth. The other way you can do your check, on the browser, is by using javascript, and validate the file before submit. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation