# isolated scope in custom diretive

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am new to isolated scope in custom directive

This is my directive

```
restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        template: '<input type="file" ng-model="myFile" />{{myFile.name}}',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, sharedServices) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileBrowser);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            element.bind("change", function(e) {
            scope.fileForImagepreview = (e.srcElement || e.target).files[0];

            if (scope.fileForImagepreview.type === "image/jpeg" ||
                scope.fileForImagepreview.type === "image/jpg" ||
                scope.fileForImagepreview.type === "image/png") {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].firstChild.files[0]);
                });
            }

            var promise = fileReader.readAsDataURL(scope.fileForImagepreview, scope);
            promise.then(function(result) {
                scope.imageSrcForPreview = result;
            });
        });
       }
```

and in html i just include it as

```
<file-browser></file-browser>
```

I want file in scope of directive

Comment: You should  Inject `sharedServices` to directive function then it will be available to you in link function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39849245/4316707 check out this answer this might give you an overview.Although m not sure why you want to create it as isolated ? Do u plan to use this multiple times in different screen.

Comment: What is the specific problem or question here?

Comment: @charlietfl There are two input fields with same model name and if i browse the  image from first input it will preview after selecting it,same for second at last two different image will be previewed.

Comment: OK..so that is an objective... now to the problem .. what is or isn't working? Do you have errors?

Comment: No there are no errors but in directive i didnt get any data in the scope.

Comment: @ajaydixit Can you create a plnuker..

Comment: @raviTeja sure i will create the plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create one array like

```
scope.imageSrcForPreview = [];
```

and insert the object into the array,so my function looks like.

```
var promise = fileReader.readAsDataURL(scope.fileForImagepreview, scope);
                promise.then(function(result) {
                    scope.imageSrcForPreview.splice(index, 1, result);
                    scope.showPreview = true;
                });
```