# How can I check if file has been chosen to upload before submitting form

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form which has an option to upload a file.

I have included a script to check if the file size is too big before the form is submitted and it works if the user is trying to upload a file greater than 2MB an alert shows, and if the file is less than 2MB the file is uploaded. I then use PHP to validate the form and process it into an email

However, if the user does not try to upload a file at all, the alert message still pops up, preventing the form from being submitted.

How can I allow the form to be submitted if the user does not want to include an upload file?
My code is:

```
<script>
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function( evt ) {
    var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];

    if(file && file.size < 2097152) { // 2 MB (this size is in bytes)
          //Submit form        
    } else {
        //Prevent default and display error
        alert("File is  over 2Mb in size!");
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

Many thanks in advance if anyone can help me find the answer.

Tog

Comment: use return false;

Comment: Where do I put that?

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam you are wrong

Comment: show your html code

Comment: check this stackoverflow Question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I allow the form to be submitted if the user does not want to include an upload file?

You need to change your if logic to **check the size and stop the form submit only if the file is present**, And not always. Right now your code checks for a file all the time and if its not present it gets into the else block hence stopping your submit event.

I would suggest you to refactor your logic as below.

```
<script>
 document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function( evt ) {
 var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];

 if(file)  // perform the size check only if a file is present.
 {
   if(file.size < 2097152) { // 2 MB (this size is in bytes)
      //Submit form        
   } else {
     //Prevent default and display error
     alert("File is  over 2Mb in size!");
     evt.preventDefault();
   }
 }    

 }, false);
</script>
```

This logic submits the form when there is no file uploaded, And when there is a file uploaded it does a check to make sure the file is less than 2 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Return true if no file selected

```
<script>
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function( evt ) {
    var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];

    if(!file)
        return true;

    if((file && file.size < 2097152)) { // 2 MB (this size is in bytes)
          //Submit form        
    } 
    else 
        //Prevent default and display error
        alert("File is  over 2Mb in size!");
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
</script>
```