# nginx file size too large message comes after uploading is completed?

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, nginx

Problem
I want to restrict the file sizes uploaded to my application server.
But entity to large message comes after uploading completed.
 
For example my nginx config is like the following 
`http { client_max_body_size 6M;}`
When the request is greater than 6MB,I expect http 413 status code, but

I am trying to uploading a 2 GB file.
after the upload is fully(2GB) completed,the gives a message '413 entity to large'.
In addition also as soon as the request came nginx, writed a message to error.log file like below 
`client intended to send too large body: 2031304213 bytes` 
but client http response comes after the file is fully loaded.

What is my fault ? Thanks

Comment: you can add validation in client side as well before sending data to server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the limit inside server section?

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 20M;
```