# How to prevent node.js from hanging when a big file upload is initiated?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload

I'm trying to protect the app I'm working on from payload DOS attacks (when someone tries to upload a **very** big file). My middlewares look like this (I'm using `express-fileupload` and `body-parser`:

```
import fileUpload from "express-fileupload";
import { json, urlencoded } from "body-parser";

// ...

app.use(
    fileUpload({
        limits: { fileSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024 }
    })
);
app.use(json({ limit: "2mb" }));
app.use(urlencoded({ limit: "2mb", extended: true }));
```

My problem is that despite the fact that I configured my middlewares to limit request size to `2mb` when I try to upload a `7gb` file the process halts.

How do I prevent this properly?

Comment: Which exact NPM modules are you using for your file upload middleware?  You show three different ones in your  question.  Which exact modules are those?

Comment: Usually it is suggested to use temp file for buffering upload data instead of memory

Comment: I tried that as well and I get the same hanging :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop the process if the size is over, use abortOnLimit option. (Otherwise, it will truncate automatically)

Like this

```
app.use(
    fileUpload({
        limits: { fileSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024 }
    }),
    abortOnLimit: true
);
```

Comment: I tried this and the proccess still hangs when I try to upload a 7 gig file :(

Comment: Ok, I tried the debug option and it turns out that node indeed stops the upload, it is just the browser that hangs. If I reload the page all is well.

Answer (score -3):

Have you considered using [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) ? As far as I know you can run specific scripts thanks to them in the background/separate thread so the main one won't be blocked.

Here's the good tutorial how to create one: [link](https://blog.logrocket.com/node-js-multithreading-what-are-worker-threads-and-why-do-they-matter-48ab102f8b10/)

EDIT:

Ok, since the above solution is not something that OP asked for here's another one - maybe try to validate file size on the front-end side? Code snippet below ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44505315/1004946))

```js
function ValidateSize(file) {
        var FileSize = file.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024; // in MB
        if (FileSize > 2) {
            alert('File size exceeds 2 MB');
           // $(file).val(''); //for clearing with Jquery
        } else {

        }
    }
```

```html
 <input onchange="ValidateSize(this)" type="file">
```

Comment: I want to prevent my users from uploading gigabytes of data instead of offloading the unnecessary operations to workers.

Comment: Web Workers are browsers-side so are no good for helping with Node.js performance. It might be possible to use Worker Threads, but I haven't a clue how to (or if they can be) hook them into Express to unburden the system from a large file upload. A good answer would explain how to do that.

Comment: I've updated my answer with different approach. Unfortunately my experience with Workers is not sufficient to deliver a solid answer example, sorry.