# Limit file size in img html tag

Tags: javascript, html

I show images uploaded on another platform on my site, but I want to protect my users from downloading extremely large files (50MB gifs for example). I dont have any control over the upload process and cant limit files during upload.

Is there any option to limit the file size of an image on a webpage?
Something like `<img src="..." maxSize="5MB" />` and the browser would cancel the download if it detects that the file is bigger than 5MB ?

Comment: you should probably use your server side language to save a copy of the image to your server whilst reducing it's size it if's too large, if you can't do that then perhaps you can use js to convert the image to base 64 and then reduce the size of that encoded image - although you would probably have to load the image source as a data attribute (otherwise the page would just download it anyway before it got converted)

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation) of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer comes with the assumption that you have permission from the other platform to use images. This kind of activity is fraught with difficulty over things like copyright. Caveat venditor.)

### Use a call to your own site as a proxy

Rather than hotlinking to the remote site directly from HTML, send requests to your own server.

From there, stream the image from the remote source. If you detect that the image is too large, you can produce an error response.

Even assuming you have permission to use images from the remote site, be sure to set the proper cache headers. You might also want to store a copy of the image on your own server.

Answer (score 0):

Before rendering the images on your site, you could perform a HEAD-request and inspect the `Content-Length` header of the response.

> ### HEAD
>
> The HTTP `HEAD` method requests the [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) that would be returned if the `HEAD` request's URL was instead requested with the HTTP GET method. For example, if a URL might produce a large download, a `HEAD` request could read its [Content-Length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length) header to check the filesize without actually downloading the file.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD

As an example, you could use the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

```js
// This URL should point to a very large image, but currently it points to an avatar
const imageUrl = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/eb03f51fd573efda46453d9b928de5e2?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG';

// Example
fetch(imageUrl, { method: 'HEAD' })
  .then(response => {
    const imageSizeInBytes = response.headers.get('content-length');
    console.log(`Image size: ${imageSizeInBytes} bytes.`);
  });
```

Comment: This answer should solve the problem, however I think from the way the question is asked, it is may unclear how to add the pictures after check to the dom. Not to render the images is may also not that clear for somebody asking this question. fetch is quite new for compatibility I would use good old XMLHttpRequest. But no reason for a down vote, since it is a valid method to solve the problem.

Comment: @overflowed thank you for the clarification.
Adding the pictures after the check could be as simple as injecting an `img` tag into the dom, but it highly depends on how the site is built. If it's a gallery of images, I would use a different approach than if it was a detail of a single image. I don't think this is the main focus of the question. 
As for `XMLHttpRequest`: browser compatibility may be a concern, but this question doesn't mention it at all. Also, the same solution would still work with `XMLHttpRequest`.