# Change measure unit when getting image weight with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image-processing

I found this solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation) question. I want to get the image weight from a file input. On the solution, the result is brought with the `MiB` (Mebibyte) unit. I wanted to know if is there some way to bring the image weight, with the same code, but on another unit, such as Megabytes.

The solution:

```
$('#file-input').bind('change', function() {
  alert('This file size is: ' + this.files[0].size/1024/1024 + "MiB");
});
```

Heres an example of how I'm doing it:

```js
$('#file-input').bind('change', function() {
  alert('This file size is: ' + this.files[0].size/1024/1024 + "MiB");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" name="" id="file-input">
```

As you can see, the unit is brought in Mebibytes. How can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.files[0].size returns the size in bytes

and `/1024/1024` converts bytes to mebibytes (1/2^20 bytes).  Simply change this to `/1000000` to convert bytes to megabytes (1/10^6 bytes)