# Max Size & File format validation in Angular HTML / TS

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Im working on a file upload in an ASP.net webpage with angular and wanted to ask how to check if the uploaded file is a pdf or jpg and has max 2MB.
If this isn't the case there should be a sipmle text which is shown and the file should not be uploaded / listed on the file list.
Can i do this in Frontend / Ts?

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the [File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). Assuming you are using an `<input>` of type `file`, you can extract the `files` property

To validate the field, perform this logic (`inputRef` is a reference to the `input` element, that may be retrieved by mean of `document.getElementById` or any function provided by the framework you are using)

```
if (!inputRef.files || inputRef.files.length === 0) {
  console.error("No files uploaded");
} else {
  const file = inputRef.files[0];
  if (['application/pdf', 'image/jpeg'].includes(file.type)) {
    console.error('File should be a pdf or a jpeg');
  } else if (file.size > 2e+6) {
    console.error('File is too large. Over 2MB');
  } else {
    console.log('File is valid');
  }
}
```

Please note that where `size` can be trusted, `type` is something that is derived by the extension hence if a user renames a file this check can still be avoided.

##### A warning on frontend validation

Use Frontend validation only to improve usability and never for security and integrity. You should check the file size and **content** on the backend. I sad content because the file extension (and derived MIME type) can never be trusted cause the file can be renamed.

As a general rule of thumb, you can avoid validating file content if the file isn't used by your server system (but only stored) and never presented to other users different than the uploader itself. Otherwise, the content may be corrupted (or even worse) and may deteriorate your system's usability.

Possible duplicate [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation)