# Getting the file size of a file in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input id="archivo" name="archivo" type="file">
```

So my field of type file is called archivo which parent is formIncidencia, so what i'm doing to find it is:

```
$('#formIncidencia').find("[id='archivo']");
```

This works fine but when i'm trying to do:

```
 $('#formIncidencia').find("[id='archivo']").files[0].size;
```

it's not working like that, and i'm uploading a file so don't know what it's happening..

Comment: Does this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation

Comment: If `id='archivo'` itself is not enough to locate the file, it's very likely that you are assigning the same ID to several fields. That breaks the ability of IDs to IDentify elements.

Comment: Yeah it helped me thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to take the first element returned by jQuery's `find`:

```js
$('button').click(() => console.log($('#formIncidencia').find("[id='archivo']")[0].files[0].size));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formIncidencia">
<input id="archivo" name="archivo" type="file">
</form>

<button>Log file size</button>
```

I guess you should just use a single selector to achieve this:

```js
$('button').click(() => console.log($('#formIncidencia > #archivo')[0].files[0].size));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formIncidencia">
<input id="archivo" name="archivo" type="file">
</form>

<button>Log file size</button>
```

Also, if your page respects the [HTML spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), it should not have more than one element with `archivo` as the `id` so even `#formIncidencia` would be superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$('#formIncidencia').find("[id='archivo']")` will return an array of matches even if you only have 1 input field. So you would have to change it to `$('#formIncidencia').find("[id='archivo']")[0].files[0].size;`.

Answer (score -1):

try the following:

```
$('#formIncidencia').find('change', function() {

  //this.files[0].size gets the size of your file.
  alert(this.files[0].size);

});
```

Comment: `bind()` has been deprecated for many years

Comment: I wanted to put `find()`

Comment: `find('change'` doesn't make sense