# How to display a meaningful error message when the upload file is too big?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, file-upload

I'm trying to limit the size of files that can be uploaded to my page. I found I can accomplish this using `RequestFormLimitsAttribute`.

```
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = MaxUploadFileLength)]
public class BulkTruckUploadModel : PageModel
{
    // ...
}
```

This definitely prevents larger files from being uploaded. But it causes Microsoft Edge to just throw up a generic error page.

[image]

Is there any way to capture this error and display a more meaningful error message?

Here is my form that submits the file.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label asp-for="BulkUpload.File" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="file" asp-for="BulkUpload.File" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BulkUpload.File" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-check form-switch mb-4">
                <input asp-for="BulkUpload.FirstRowHasHeaders" class="form-check-input">
                <label asp-for="BulkUpload.FirstRowHasHeaders" class="form-check-label"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <a class="btn btn-secondary" asp-page="Trucks">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here's my handler that gets the file.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            // Read the file from BulkUpload.File.OpenReadStream()
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions
        }
    }
    return Page();
}
```

**Update:** The goal here is to prevent denial-of-service attacks by someone trying to upload enormous files. I could also just remove the size limitation and then check the file length property from code. But it isn't clear to me if this approach prevents very large files from impacting the server. (Does this prevent uploading big files, or just check the length after they've been uploaded?)

Comment: you can define a custom error page, but it sounds like you want to validate on backend or frontend.  For backend, you'd want to increase the limit so the error is not thrown and then check the file's size (IFormFile.length returns the size in bytes methinks).  For frontend, you could check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation  Probably a better option so you can leave the server limit as is.

Comment: How exactly are you POSTing the file?

Comment: @SalmanA: Just a regular form with file input element.

Comment: So the form posts to the page directly the old fashioned way or via ajax? And what happens if the upload succeeds? Does the server send some html, json or redirect (sorry if this is too many questions but we need to know where to place the meaningful error message)

Comment: It sounds like posting "The old fashioned way". Assuming that is the case, you could create an exception filter for a InvalidDataException (assuming this is what exception is being thrown when your application throws you back to the error page).

This exception filter could redirect the user to a more meaningful error page.

Comment: @SalmanA: I've added my markup and server-side code to the question. I know there are other ways to upload a file, but as far as I know, I'm doing it the basic and simple way.

Comment: @PhilGolding: As best I can tell, my handler is not even being called. And so I have no way to add appropriate exception handling in my post handler.

Comment: What web server are you using? I mean how is your web application setup? This is relevant to the update in your question.

Comment: @SalmanA: It's ASP.NET Core running on IIS.

Comment: @VonC's answer is definitely the way to go. Out of curiosity I was browsing the ASP.NET Core source to see at what point in the pipeline it would check the content length against the `RequestFormLimits` attribute properties and how it responds when they're exceeded. The framework tries to buffer the entire content while setting up the model binding and throws an exception if the limit is exceeded during read. The controller method won't ever get called if the exception is thrown, so `if (ModelState.IsValid)` would never get reached. You've got to handle the exception through middleware.

Comment: @EmperorEto: Yes, there's no controller here (this is Razor Pages). But my post handler is clearly never called. It doesn't get that far. So I agree with your assessment.

Answer (score 5):

When using [`RequestFormLimitsAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.requestformlimitsattribute?view=aspnetcore-8.0) in ASP.NET Core to limit the size of file uploads, you can encounter less-than-ideal error pages if a user tries to upload a file that exceeds the specified limit. To handle this more gracefully, you can catch the specific exception that is thrown when the limit is exceeded and then provide a custom error message to the user.

- Use exception handling middleware to catch the [`BadHttpRequestException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.badhttprequestexception?view=aspnetcore-8.0) which is thrown when the size limit is exceeded.
- Provide a custom error response or redirect the user to a custom error page.

The `Configure` method of your `Startup.cs` would be:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // Use exception handling middleware to catch file size exceptions
    app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
    {
        errorApp.Run(async context =>
        {
            var exceptionHandlerPathFeature =
                context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

            var exception = exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error;

            // Check if the exception is due to a large file upload
            if (exception is BadHttpRequestException badHttpRequestException &&
                badHttpRequestException.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status413RequestEntityTooLarge)
            {
                // Set the response status code and content type
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status413RequestEntityTooLarge;
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

                // Provide your custom error message
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("<html><body><h1>File too large</h1>" +
                    "<p>The file you are trying to upload exceeds the maximum allowed size.</p></body></html>");
            }
        });
    });

    // Other middleware registrations
}
```

---

[Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5475636/phil-golding)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78076510/how-to-display-a-meaningful-error-message-when-the-upload-file-is-too-big#comment137670093_78076510) about using an exception filter to handle `InvalidDataException` is a viable approach when dealing with traditional form submissions in ASP.NET Core. An exception filter can intercept specific exceptions that are thrown during the processing of a request and allow you to redirect the user to a custom error page or perform other custom error handling logic.

```cs
public class InvalidDataExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is InvalidDataException)
        {
            // Log the exception details if necessary

            // Redirect to a custom error page or modify the response directly
            context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Error", "Home", new { message = "The file you tried to upload is too large." });
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you would register this filter in your `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new InvalidDataExceptionFilter());
    });
    // Other service configurations
}
```

That filter will catch `InvalidDataException` exceptions thrown by any action in your application, allowing you to handle them in a centralized way.

The type of exception to be caught (`InvalidDataException` in this case) should be the one actually thrown by the framework when the file size limit is exceeded. You might need to adjust the exception type if a different one is thrown in your particular case.

---

To address your update regarding the prevention of denial-of-service attacks by checking file sizes after upload: the approach of using [`RequestFormLimitsAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-8.0#multipart-body-length-limit) or similar settings in `appsettings.json` is designed to prevent the server from processing giant files in the first place, which is beneficial for protecting against such attacks. Checking the file length after it has been uploaded would not offer the same level of protection, as the large file would still have been transmitted to the server.

---

Client-side validation provides immediate feedback to the user, which is helpful for user experience, but it should not be the only line of defense. Server-side validation is important for security.

```bash
Client-side (Browser)   ↔   Server-side (ASP.NET Core)
   │                                 │
   │ 1. Check file size              │
   │    before upload                │
   │    (using JavaScript)           │
   │                                 │
   │ ←───────────────────────────────│
   │                                 │
   │ 2. If file size is within       │
   │    acceptable limits, upload    │
   │                                 │
   │───────────────────────────────→ │
   │                                 │
   │                                 │ 3. Check file size again (optional)
   │                                 │    and process file
   │                                 │
   │                                 │
   └───────────────────────────────→ │
                                     │ 4. If an error occurs (e.g., file too big),
                                     │    return a custom error page
```

For server-side validation in ASP.NET Core, see above.
For the client-side, you can implement a JavaScript check before the file is uploaded, as described in the Stack Overflow comments. Here is a function you might include in your HTML page:

```js
function checkFileSize(maxFileSize) {
    var input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var file = input.files[0];
        if (file.size > maxFileSize) {
            alert("File size should not exceed " + maxFileSize + " bytes.");
            // Prevent form submission or clear the file input
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You would then call this function on your form's submit event or file input's change event, passing the maximum file size you want to allow.

---

As noted by [Phil Golding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5475636/phil-golding) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78076510/how-to-display-a-meaningful-error-message-when-the-upload-file-is-too-big/78091010#comment137670732_78091010), if you are using [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio), then the setup for adding filters will be a bit different compared to a traditional MVC application: you would need to register filters with the `AddRazorPagesOptions` call.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new InvalidDataExceptionFilter());
        // other options 
    });
    // Other service configurations
}
```

---

> I had hoped it was as simple as checking the Length property of the `IFormFile`. But I guess that is too late to stop an enormous file upload?

Checking the `Length` property of `IFormFile` would have a significant limitation: the `Length` property can only be accessed... *after* the file has been uploaded to the server. That means that if a user tries to upload an enormous file, the server will first accept and process the *entire file* before any checks can be made. That is not efficient and could indeed lead to a denial-of-service condition if the server resources are exhausted.

The `RequestFormLimitsAttribute` and similar settings in `appsettings.json` are more effective because they allow the server to reject the request early, without processing the entire file, if it exceeds the specified size limit.

However, your form is a standard HTML form that posts data synchronously, not via AJAX. In this scenario, you cannot intercept the response using client-side JavaScript if the server rejects the file due to size limits. If the server is set up to return a custom error page for large file uploads, as described earlier, then the browser will display that page instead of the default error page.

To summarize:

- To prevent large files from impacting the server, you should keep the `RequestFormLimitsAttribute` or similar server-side settings to reject oversized files early in the request processing.
- Adding client-side validation is helpful for the user experience but does not prevent large files from being sent to the server.
- Using exception handling middleware or filters is the correct approach to intercept the error and provide a custom response to the user.
- When using Razor Pages, you should use `AddRazorPagesOptions` to add filters.

---

> But note than `RequestFormLimitsAttribute` / `MultipartBodyLengthLimit` limits the size of *one* "body part".
> A malicious user can upload 100 files at once, each within the limit. The limit you should impose is [`MaxRequestBodySize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-8.0#kestrel-maximum-request-body-size)... the maximum size of payload (possibly in conjunction with body part length limit).
> This could be done on a per action or all requests basis. Should work with OP unless the app is set up differently.

True: you need an appropriate limit not only for individual file uploads but also for the total request body size to prevent a user from bypassing the file size restriction by uploading multiple files that cumulatively exceed acceptable limits.

That would mean to:

- update your server configuration to limit the maximum request body size using `MaxRequestBodySize`. That setting is particularly important when using Kestrel as the web server.
- configure this limit globally or on a per-action basis, depending on the requirements of your application.

Since the OP is using IIS, note that IIS has its own request filtering settings that can limit the size of the request body.

From ["App startup in ASP.NET Core"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-5.0&preserve-view=true#the-configureservices-method), your `ConfigureServices()` method would be:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MaxRequestBodySize = 52428800; // for example, to set the limit to 50MB
    });

    services.AddRazorPages(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new InvalidDataExceptionFilter());
    });
    // Other service configurations...
}
```

And you can set the maximum request body size in IIS via the [`web.config` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-5.0) (see "[Application configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/in-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-8.0#application-configuration)", as part of "[Other Kestrel limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-8.0)"):

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <!-- This will handle the entire request size -->
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" /> <!-- Value is in bytes, 50MB example -->
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

`maxAllowedContentLength` is measured in bytes, and the default value is approximately 28.6 MB (30000000 bytes). If you set this limit in `web.config`, make sure it aligns with the limit set in your ASP.NET Core configuration to prevent conflicts.

---

> My actual limitation will be more like 64k. It's a smaller file. I just want to keep it that way. For that reason, a JavaScript library seems like overkill for my needs.

For applications running behind IIS, it is important to make sure the IIS settings are aligned with your ASP.NET Core configurations. That means setting the `maxAllowedContentLength` in the `web.config` file to match or exceed the limits you configure in your application, so IIS does not preemptively reject large requests before they reach your ASP.NET Core middleware or filters.

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <!-- Set maxAllowedContentLength to 64KB (65536 bytes) -->
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="65536" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can configure `MaxRequestBodySize` in your `Startup.cs` for specific actions or globally. However, note that the setting for `MaxRequestBodySize` might not be effective when running behind IIS due to the `maxAllowedContentLength` setting in IIS taking precedence. It is essential to configure both IIS and ASP.NET Core to make sure consistent behavior.

Considering your concern about not wanting to use a heavy JavaScript library for file size validation due to the relatively small size limit (64KB), a simple client-side check using vanilla JavaScript is sufficient and not overkill. That can prevent users from attempting to upload files that exceed the limit before the request is sent to the server.

For instance:

```html
<script>
document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    if (file && file.size > 65536) { // 64KB limit
        alert("File size must not exceed 64KB.");
        e.target.value = ''; // Reset the file input
    }
});
</script>
```

---

> I have no `startup.cs`.
> But I do have a `WebApplication` after calling `WebApplicationBuilder.Build()`. It does not appear to be working.
> Can you elaborate on Razor Pages and adding filters?

If you are using Razor Pages, but no `Startup.cs` file, that should mean a simplified startup experience introduced in .NET 6 and later versions.
In this setup, the application configuration, including middleware and services setup, [is in the `Program.cs` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio), leveraging the [`WebApplication` builder pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplicationbuilder?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

For adding filters in a Razor Pages application *without* a `Startup.cs` file, the process slightly differs from the traditional MVC setup. Instead of using `.AddMvcOptions`, you directly configure the services for Razor Pages and add filters within the `Program.cs` file using [`AddRazorPagesOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcrazorpagesmvcbuilderextensions.addrazorpagesoptions?view=aspnetcore-8.0), with conventions to modify the page application model, rather than directly adding filters as you might in an MVC context.

Since the direct addition of an `InvalidDataExceptionFilter` through `AddMvcOptions` did not work as expected, try a [`ConfigureFilter` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pageconventioncollectionextensions.configurefilter?view=aspnetcore-8.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-pageconventioncollectionextensions-configurefilter(microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-applicationmodels-pageconventioncollection-system-func((microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-applicationmodels-pageapplicationmodel-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-filters-ifiltermetadata)))), which applies filters across your Razor Pages application, either through specifying a type, using a factory, or even inline with a lambda expression.

Source: "[Razor Pages route and app conventions in ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/1192764b9c2c9b71eaec9505a41cbf4f06be9a8c/aspnetcore/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions.md)"

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    // Apply a filter globally to all Razor Pages
    options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(builder => new InvalidDataExceptionFilter());
});
```

If the handler not being called, check if the conditions under which the filter is supposed to activate are indeed met. If the filter is designed to catch exceptions, make sure that such exceptions are thrown within the Razor Pages' handler methods where the filter can intercept them.

This assumes the filter itself is implemented correctly, adhering to the expected filter interfaces ([`IPageFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.ipagefilter?view=aspnetcore-8.0), [`IAsyncPageFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iasyncpagefilter?view=aspnetcore-8.0), or other applicable MVC filter interfaces if the filter is expected to work in both MVC and Razor Pages contexts).

Regarding the `WebApplication` configuration, once you have built your application configuration using `WebApplicationBuilder`, you use the `app` instance (resulting from `builder.Build()`) to set up middleware, routing, and other HTTP pipeline settings. The `app.Run();` at the end starts handling incoming requests according to the configured pipeline.

Comment: Only additional thing I have to add is that the OP is using razor pages, so probably has a slightly different setup, and probably needs to chain .AddMvcOptions(options => options.Filters.Add...) after Services.AddRazorPages()

Comment: A very thorough answer. But note than RequestFormLimitsAttribute / MultipartBodyLengthLimit limits the size of one "body part". A malicious user can upload 100 files at once, each within the limit. The limit you should impose is [MaxRequestBodySize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-8.0#kestrel-maximum-request-body-size)... the maximum size of payload (possibly in conjunction with body part length limit). This could be done on per action or all requests basis. Should work with OPs unless the app is setup differently.

Comment: @SalmanA Good point, thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, as well as some additional configuration, tailored for IIS.

Comment: @JonathanWood I have edited the answer to address your last comment/question.

Comment: Note that your code for adding the filter for Razor Pages does not compile. The `options` parameter is of type `RazorPagesOptions`, which has no `Filters` property. I'm not sure where you got that code. I'm having trouble finding a lot of information on this.

Comment: I got it to compile using `builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{ ... }).AddMvcOptions(options => { options.Filters.Add(new InvalidDataExceptionFilter()); });`. Unfortunately, the handler is never called. Looking at abandoning this approach. I can't believe the lack of good information on this technique!

Comment: @JonathanWood I have rewritten the last section, using the documentation "[Razor Pages route and app conventions in ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/1192764b9c2c9b71eaec9505a41cbf4f06be9a8c/aspnetcore/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions.md)".

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It doesn't work. I've spent enough time on this. I'm giving up on this approach!

Comment: @JonathanWood I am sorry for that. Don't hesitate to write an answer here if you find another approach. You can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of displaying any meaning full display of error message, I would recommend using JavaScript File Uploader, in which you can identify the file size and prevent upload right there in the browser. Which I guess other answer has also recommended.
2. For optimum performance, I would recommend maximum file upload size to 4 MB, and basically breaking file inside browser into multiple parts and upload each part as a separate request. Thus reducing the server buffer. And at the end, write a commit action to combine all files on server (Both S3 and Azure Blobs provide multipart uploads). Where in you upload file in parts and at the end run a commit API to save file.
3. And for DDOS protection, I would recommend using library such as "RateLimiter". ASP.NET core provides new inbuilt rate limiter, there is also an open source github repo, https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit , which you can use it. Basically it is not very difficult to do it, however, you can easily guess how much parallel connections you want to allow.

Comment: My actual limitation will be more like 64k. It's a smaller file. I just want to keep it that way. For that reason, a JavaScript library seems like overkill for my needs.

Comment: @JonathanWood It depends upon the average file size, since we are going to allow audio/video and high res photos, 64k leads to more overhead. Average photos is roughly 30mb and average video is roughly half GB.

Comment: I didn't really follow that. In my case I don't want to allow audio, video or photos. 64k will be okay. I don't want to allow the users to upload bigger files than that. I'm not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: @JonathanWood, In our case, large files are sliced down to 4MB parts, and each part is uploaded, since your files will be very small, you can ignore parts uploader and you can simply put rate limiter and javascript file size validation.